# Sum of digits of n^n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can I receive some assistance please. I was going through some questions when is saw this one,

Let A be the sum of the digits of 16^16. Let B be the sum of the digits of A. What is the sum of the digits of B without finding A.

Well, initially I thought that the sum of the digits of 16^n was (6n + 1) but that fails for n>10. Help?

Answer (score 4):

A little estimating shows that $16^{16}$ has $20$ digits.  Therefore $A≤180$.  Therefore $B≤27$.

Now, if you kept on iterating the digit sum, you'd get to $7$ since $16^{16}\equiv 7 \pmod 9$.  Thus $B\equiv 7 \pmod 9$  So $B\in \{7,16,25\}$.

It follows that the sum of the digits of $B$ is $7$.

Worth noting: a simple search through the possible values for $A$ shows that $25$ is not possible, but both $7$ and $16$ are.  I don't see an easy way to eliminate either of these.  In truth, $B=16$ but I don't see how to get there without heavier computation.

Comment: You don't even need to check that 25 is not possible as a value for $B$, since in that case the sum of digits of $B$ is still 7. All you need is $B < 79$

Comment: @RolfHoyer  You mean $A$?  But $A=88$ as it happens.  I agree that you don;'t need to eliminate $25$ to see that the digit sum of $B$ is $7$ (and have edited accordingly).

Comment: Well $79$ is the smallest value possible for $B$ that is equal to 7 modulo 9 but with a digital sum greater than 7. The corresponding bound on $A$ would be $A < 799999999$, ie the smallest number equal to 7 modulo 9 with a digital sum at least 79.

Comment: Wouldn’t *B* < or equal to 17 and not 27?

Comment: @VaraunRamgoolie  Oh, you can definitely get a better estimate on $B$, no question.  As I say (for different reasons) it's not hard to show that $B$ is either $7$  or $16$.  I just don't see an elementary way to rule out $7$.  Just tightening the bound on $B$ isn't going to do that, so far as I can see.